# Flutter How to implement this type of dropdown , see attached image

Tags: flutter

Flutter How to implement this type of dropdown? See attached image:

[image]  Flutter

Comment: check [Autocomplete](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html) - the docs say: *"A widget for helping the user make a selection by entering some text and choosing from among a list of options."*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.